# MATLAB Surface Plot with Vectors

Tags: matlab

How to make the surface plot of the three vectors with following dimentions in MATLAB using Surf function.

Dimension of vector x= 43x1

Dimension of vector y= 10x1

Dimension of vector z= 43x1

I have three vectors x, y, z with above dimensions. When I tried, it says dimension does not match. Please help.

Comment: that means exactly that: dimensions of the arrays do not match. your `z` variable should be 43x10. How does your function z changes with x and y?

Comment: Is the `z` variable consistent along one of the axes `x` or `y`? That's the only possibility for `z` being a 1D vector.